# How to include a caption (a cck field) in lightbox?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm working on a theme i bought and since i'm just learning php i'm having a hard time including a field as a description text in the lightbox once the thumbnail is clicked.

Here's the code (that's in the tpl.php file) that outputs the thumbnails (from a view)

```
<?php
if (isset($fields['field_image']->content) and strpos($fields['field_image']->content, '<img')) {
 print str_replace('<a ', '<a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" ', $fields['field_image']->content); ...
?>
```

Here's the html version of the lightbox script :

```
<a href="images/fullscreen/1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" title="caption."><img ...
```

How can in include the caption tag ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Relevant question that may be of help: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29252/get-the-title-attribute-into-a-lightbox-frame/141870#141870

Answer (score 1):

```
<a title="caption"><img alt="description"></a>
```

Both the caption and the description will be displayed on the image preview.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for the reply but i don't really understand what you said. 
The html version i used is just an example of how the script works.  
  
What i want is a way to dynamically include the caption in the php script. (the one that's in the tpl.php file)  
  
I can hardcode it and it would be something like this :  



`print str_replace('<a ', '<a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" title="Hardcoded Caption" '...`

Comment: Ok, so do you ask how to access a CCK field or how to embody a string in the lightbox frame ?

Comment: Yes i want to access a cck field and include it in the lightbox script as a caption

Screenshot : [https://img.skitch.com/20120112-cihwefn7nq18ysu53uhruniui3.jpg]

Comment: Ok, there exist a basic approach to this problem. Type `<pre><?php print_r($node); ?></pre>` in node.tpl.php to see what's available in the node object (what fields, how formatted, etc.) and then take what you want and output it to the lightbox. I hope that's what you need..

Comment: I fail to understand how this answer is helpful to the question asked.